# Files with special characters in their file name load locally but not live

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, urlencode

I converted a Drupal website to a static site using sitesucker (Mac tool). I am running MAMP 6 locally. Some images are missing live, probably because of an encoding issue.

For instance, I have this file:

`Akzeptanz_GoA3+_Vorschaubild_Symbolbild_pexels-jéshoots-253647.jpg`

And both locally and live it is embedded exactly like this:

`<img src="/path/Akzeptanz_GoA3+_Vorschaubild_Symbolbild_pexels-je%CC%81shoots-253647.jpg">`

Locally the image works, Live it is 404. What could be the reasons and possible solutions to this different behaviour? Live is a regular LAMP stack.

This behavior consists when I empty both htaccess files.

Comment: Reason is probably either a different character encoding used by the underlying file system; or a problem with Unicode normalization. The character `é` in UTF-8, URL-encoded, would result in `%C3%A9`. In your URL however you have a "standard" `e`, followed by `%CC%81`, and the latter is the encoding of the COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT.

Comment: @CBroe you again! :) Thanks! Do you have any idea how I could go on and debug this?

Comment: @CBroe I found out locally I run Darwin, Live is Linux (uname)

Comment: Does it work on your live system, with `/path/Akzeptanz_GoA3+_Vorschaubild_Symbolbild_pexels-j%C3%A9shoots-253647.jpg`?

Comment: @CBroe yes it loads. Chrome shows `Akzeptanz_GoA3+_Vorschaubild_Symbolbild_pexels-jéshoots-253647.jpg` in the address bar though. When I change it in the src attribute it stays like that and loads

Comment: Looks like it is indeed an issue with unicode normalization then; your local system apparently is able to resolve this somehow, whereas your live system isn't. I am not sure how or if it is possible to change that behavior. Replacing the sequences in the URLs might be the best option.

Comment: @CBroe hm thanks, thats a bummer though. Looks like this is the same: https://serverfault.com/questions/839724/apache-serve-files-with-different-url-encode Thanks for your help so far

Comment: @CBroe do you think this could be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643402/convert-unicode-decomposition-when-transferring-files-to-web-server

Comment: Or maybe something convmv could solve? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595562/how-to-convert-utf8-nfc-files-to-utf8-nfd-with-convmv-on-mac-os-high-sierra

Comment: Can't tell from that discussion over there, if that would fix it going in the "right" direction. You would have to get any filename that contains the actual `é` character, translated into the version of `e` followed by the diacritical mark, because that's how it is encoded in your URLs. If it did the "other direction", then you likely won't win much here in this situation.

Comment: In my experience, this is not worth the hustle. Encoding in file system objects can differ vastly and there's no simple way to detect it, plus not all your supporting tools will handle it nicely. It's better to have ASCII-compatible names (either derived from original name or fully random) and leave the original name for response headers whenever applies. (No idea how to handle this in Drupal).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Well, the site is quite big and I cannot change all of this. I hoped for a simple batch solution

Comment: How are you URL-encoding this URL when embedding in the HTML source?

Answer (score 0):

"Fixing" the URL encoding in the HTML source would be the preferred solution, as mentioned in comments (from `e%CC%81` to `%C3%A9`). (Or even "normalising" the filename, so URL-encoding is not an issue.)

However, if that is not an option then you could perhaps do a search/replace in `.htaccess`.

For example, near the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
# Replace "e%CC%81" with "%C3%A9"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/(.*)e%CC%81([^\s]*)
RewriteRule ^path/ %1\%C3\%A9%2 [NE,L]
```

Include a `/path/` in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (as above) to limit the number of URLs tested.

We match (and capture) the requested URL in the preceding *condition* against `THE_REQUEST` server variable, which preserves the URL-encoded URL that was actually requested.

The literal `%` in the *substitution* string should be backslash-escaped to avoid potentially being interpreted as a backreference (although since they are not followed by a digit, that should be OK).

---

> Chrome shows `Akzeptanz_GoA3+_Vorschaubild_Symbolbild_pexels-jéshoots-253647.jpg` in the address bar though. When I change it in the src attribute it stays like that and loads

Chrome will often show the more friendly URL-decoded URL in the address bar, even if the underlying request is URL-encoded.

When you change it in the `src` attribute (to the URL-decoded version I assume) then the *browser* automatically "fixes" it and URL-encodes the URL in the HTTP request (you can examine the Network traffic in the browser dev tools).

Comment: Thanks so far! The RewriteRules throw a 500 error, though

Comment: @Alex Try changing the `L` flag for `END`. You could also try (temporarily) changing this to an external redirect (eg. `RewriteRule ^path/ /%1\%C3\%A9%2 [R,NE,L]` - note the slash prefix on the _substitution_ string). However, I can't immediately see an error with this rule. Can you please check your server's error log for the details of the 500 error. _Aside:_ If this only applies to `.jpg` files then the regex could be further restricted.